# Checking a multi-line transaction for fields containing all nulls

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a transaction table where the complete transaction (tranid) spans multiple rows per the example below

[image: TransactionExample]

What I'm trying to find are transactions that contain all nulls vs tranid's that only partially have nulls, and only showing tranid's where every column is null under acount_id vs only 2 of the 6 in the example above.

I have the following query written, but searching for "is null" only produces the two lines of the first transaction that have nulls vs searching an entire transaction for all nulls. I'm not sure how I'd search for that, and am hoping someone could help with the logic here.

```
select * 
from ns.tItemFulfillment itf 
    inner join ns.tsalesorder so on itf.created_from_id = so.transaction_id
    left join ns.tpurchaseorder tpo on so.transaction_id = tpo.created_from_id
    inner join ns.transaction_lines tl on itf.transaction_id = tl.transaction_id
    left join ns.accounts a on tl.account_id = a.account_id
where tl.account_ID IS NULL and tpo.created_from_id is null
```

produces the following, which as you can see is only the last two lines of the transaction above.

[image]

I should be able to only query tranid's with all nulls, which is what I need help with. Thank you

Comment: Which columns need to be null? Literally all except the tranid?

Comment: account_id and accountnumber both need to be null. The rest can have data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use aggregation:

```
select tranid
from mytable —- or whatever join you need
group by tranid
having max(account_id) is null
and max(account_number) is null
—- etc for all columns that need to be all null
```

Comment: Thanks! That did it